# Calculus on C# Windows form VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a question for doing mathematics calculus integration.
I'm just a beginner so sorry if i did not explain the question clearly and asking some noob question.

Any recommend library to use or is there any others way to do integration?

My Question is:

```
P=1/(SQRT 2*PI)∫(upper limit X, lower limit negative infinity)e^((-1/2t)^2) dt
```

i will have the `X` 
But how am i going to code the integration in?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking for here. Mathematics help? Development help?

Comment: Hi, mainly i just wanted to call a method of integration, i can do the sqrt and others, but i cant do integration. I'm doing an inventory analysis, so need to calculate the possibility of running out of stock. The formaular above i can key into calculator but in C# i have no idea how to do the integration

Comment: .NET doesn't have any calculus functionality. But you should be able to work out what the integration is mathematically, which will give you a function to implement. This is really a maths question more than a developer question as far as I can see.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.
So you mean that i need to create a integration function my own?

Comment: Apart of using the wrong language for this kind of calculation your most likely also have an error in your integral because as it is now it simply doesn't converge. What you probably meant to write is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fsqrt%282*pi%29+*+int+e%5E%28-0.5*t%5E2%29%2C+t%3D-inf..x).

Comment: Hey Dirk. This is the formula that i want.
So i can use this? 1/sqrt(2*pi) * int e^(-0.5*t^2), t=-inf..x
what is the .. mean?
Thanks for replying!

Comment: And It do have the int which .NET dont have that library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated above, .NET does not come with Calculus Integration class out of the box. Integration could be performed either from integration tables (for well known functions such as Cos, Sin, etc.) or by using a method of Numerical integration such as Simpson's Rule or Newton Cotes Trapezium Rule.

You could code your method of choice using C# yourself (example: [Integration using trapezoidal rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741824/more-efficient-integration-loop)) or use a 3rd party tool. [Math.Net](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) is an open source library for such methods. Also, check this answer:[Recommended Math Library for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387430/recommended-math-library-for-c-net).

If the function being integrated is variable and is not to be hard-coded, you'd also need a component to help you evaluate expressions dynamically at run-time. Some free ones exist. Let me know if you need this.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Still trying to digest the trapezoidal rule. I'm not strong in maths. Thanks!

Comment: It is prety simple in fact. You divide the area under the curve into rectangles and sum area of each to get the approximate area under the curve. example:http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ApproximatingDefIntegrals.aspx

Comment: Thanks! This somehow make sense to me! Thanks very much!